# TimeCapsule occasionally stuck for hours

Tags: backup, time-machine, time-capsule

Typically, the TimeMachine backups on TimeCapsule are fast and reliable.

But occasionally, the backup is just stuck for hours not backing up the data at all or just 10 MB can take minutes.

- The connectivity is fine. It's fast and reliable.
  - There is plenty of space both on Mac and TimeCapsule
- `sudo sysctl debug.lowpri_throttle_enabled=1` didn't help
- no `THROTTLED` entries in `sudo fs_usage backupd`
- The Mac is doing next to nothing
- backupd process eats all between 0 and 10 %, peaking at around 30 % of CPU occasionally (the % doesn't seem to influence the actual speed)
- probably something related to Mac, because it got stuck in 2 TimeMachines
- TimeCapsule was restarted

It didn't finish just 30 GB backup the whole day. Multiple unsuccessful tries on multiple days.
Catalina (last version for Intel)

What else could be wrong?

EDIT: It got stuck on my second TimeCapsule (in different location) as well, so it is probably related to the Mac.

Comment: I did a new backup and that was fast. It took 3 h full backup where several 6 h attempts to do an incremental backups weren't successful. Still curious if anybody have an idea how the backup can get stuck like that, I kept the old problematic backup ti investigate.

Comment: I've no experience of the problem, but some of the notes in this blog may be of use. Also it doesn't specifically relate to Time Capsule so YMMV. Of note is the last comment on the post related to excluding  /Users/shared/adi. I recently setup a new TM backup on a Catalina machine I'm resurrecting prior to replacement in a few weeks, and I noticed that this was automatically included, so perhaps Apple are on top of it already

https://eclecticlight.co/2020/02/08/time-machine-12-backups-that-never-complete/

I'm specifically including this as a comment as I can't state it's an answer.